# Hive Data Integration error in Pentaho

Tags: hive, bigdata, pentaho, data-integration, impala

I am using Bigdata Lite3.0, Pentaho 5.1, CDH5.0. I want to connect Hive tables using Pentaho.

While trying to connect, i am getting below errors.

```
Error connecting to database [Hive] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:428)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:361)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:314)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:302)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2685)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.test(DatabaseDialog.java:109)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.test(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:157)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2$3.widgetSelected(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:147)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizard.createAndRunDatabaseWizard(CreateDatabaseWizard.java:111)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createDatabaseWizard(Spoon.java:7457)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1297)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7801)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9130)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:638)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:151)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:573)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:410)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.getActiveDriver(HiveDriver.java:107)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.callWithActiveDriver(HiveDriver.java:121)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:132)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:555)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.getActiveDriver(HiveDriver.java:105)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load JDBC driver of type: hive2
at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.CommonHadoopShim.getJdbcDriver(CommonHadoopShim.java:108)
... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: JDBC driver of type 'hive2' not supported
at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.CommonHadoopShim.getJdbcDriver(CommonHadoopShim.java:104)
... 54 more
```

Hostname : localhost
Port : 8888
Database name : default

Awaiting for you reply

Regards,
Jiten

Comment: How do you connect? Show us **all** code that is **necessary**.

Answer (score 3):

Did you edit plugin.properties in the plugin folder??

```
data-integration > plugins > pentaho-big-data-plugin > plugin.properties
```

change the property "active.hadoop.configuration" to the hadoop distribution you are using, eg :

```
active.hadoop.configuration=cdh50
```

This might solve the issue.

Comment: Yes i have modified it, but still getting same error. I have installed Big Data Lite 2.5 and using Pentaho 5.1. Hive connection details: hostname: localhost, database: default, port: 8888. But the system hangs at the last step of connection creation.

Comment: Check the port. Default port for Hive server2 is 10000.

Comment: I would suggest make a fresh install of PDI. Do not change anything other than plugin.properties file..it will work fine. Also try mentioning your IP as hostname.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Shailvi's answer, it depends on the Hive distribution running on the Server. Once the version/distribution has been determined, identify the hadoop distributions bundled along with the Pentaho installation, and modify the value for the property `active.hadoop.configuration`.